# PHP How can find a string start with an end tag to get the string from inside?

Tags: php, regex

```
$stringText = 'Example text [1212sdas|4542189789/] continue text...
```

My result finally is an array with: `['1212sdas|4542189789']`

My text is:

> "Example text [1212sdas|4542189789/]..."

My result should be:

`array('1212sdas|4542189789'`

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
((?<=\[).*?(?=\/\]))
```

It matches smallest pattern that has `[` on the left and `\]` on the right.

`(?<=...)` is positive lookback that means what should be on the left.
`(?=...)` is positive lookahead that means what should be on the right.
.*? means any smallest pattern that regex could find. otherwise it match all character between the first `[` and the last `\]` .

[Demo](https://regexr.com/6767k)

Comment: Either you use lookarounds `~(?<=\[).*?(?=/])~` or you use a capture group `~\[(.*?)/]~`, but it doesn't make sense to use both. Note also that the closing square bracket isn't a special character for pcre and doesn't need to be escaped.